# Function returning Optional("String")

Tags: swift, option-type

I have this function that accepts an Double value, convert it to a currency format and return a String formatted like R$:1.200,30.

```
func convert_Value(valor: Double) ->String {
    let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.CurrencyStyle
    formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "pt_BR")
    return ("\(formatter.stringFromNumber(valor))")
}
```

This function doesn't have any Optional variable declared, but when i call it using:

```
x = convert_Value(1200.30)
```

it returns:

```
Optional("R$1.200,30")
```

I can't figure out what i need to do, as its not an optional i can't use exclamation marks to unwrap the optional.
I tried to turn the Double and String parameter in function as Optional and then unwrap, but the Optional stills showing.

Comment: The formatter `stringFromNumber` method returns an Optional. So `formatter.stringFromNumber(valor)` is probably what you want to (safely) unwrap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't return `Optional("R$1.200,30")`, it returns `"Optional("R$1.200,30")"`. There's a subtle difference there; notice the `"`. What's happening is `formatter.stringFromNumber(valor)` returns `String?`, which you're putting in a `String` using `"\(...)"`. Instead, you should return `formatter.stringFromNumber(valor)!`, force unwrapping here is okay because you know the input is a number.

Comment: I think i need some air. I didn't noticed the optional inside the string. Thanks!